# Delete or Update AgentWork record

Tags: apex, service-cloud-console, servicecloud, omnichannel

We have implemented Omni Channel in our Salesforce system. Our implementation is complex, incorporating skill-based routing, and we create PSR records using flows and Apex.

When a Case record is created, it is assigned to a Queue. Based on conditions, we create a PSR record.
Now if that case is manually assigned to agents, an AgentWork record is created with the status **Assigned**, since the case is already assigned to an agent, it is still getting recommended by Omni Channel to the owner of that case.

I have gone through salesforce documentation given here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_agentwork.htm

I have two requirements: either update its status to 'Opened' so that it won't be recommended by Omni Channel and will be counted in total capacity, or allow the deletion of that record. According to Salesforce documentation, neither option is possible.

What other options do I have, so that the cases owned by individual users don't get recommended buy Omnichannel?